# What is the best approach in mimicking a flash based application on iPad?

Tags: jquery, ios

http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/interactive/timelines/british/index_embed.shtml

This application at hand is flash based. Can this be accomplished on an iPad possibly via cocos2d? Or is the better approach just trying to do it in jQuery and using a WebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would go with JS to do this. It shouldnt be that hard. The zooming in animation would be the hardest part. jQuery would be good, and I'd use canvas also. Canvas will allow you to do a lot better animations and it'll run a lot faster. Hell, they run a multiplayer Quake game in canvas. I'm not sure what your team is like and what their skillsets are but that's what I'd suggest. Also, you could use SVG. Either canvas or SVG with jQuery you can make some slick applications. Here are some links for ya:

jQuery like SVG library: http://raphaeljs.com/

jQuery's creator John Resig made this Cavnas library: http://processingjs.org/

Last One I suggest is Fabric.js. Haven't tried it, but looks great:
http://www.slideshare.net/kangax/fabricjs-building-acanvaslibrarybk

Great demo of it with link to downlad: http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo/